# Receiving 'Compiler Error: Object required' Error

Tags: vba, excel

I receive a `'Compiler Error: Object required'` error in the following code:

```
Sub TF()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TF As Long 'Value 'Range
    Set TF = Application.Match("TF", Sheets("Update").Range("1:1"), False) '.Value

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
            rng.Cells(i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Update").Range("A:AZ"), TF, False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA coding and am unsure of what may be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.Match` returns a variant and hence do these things

1. Change `Dim TF As Long` to `Dim TF As Variant`
2. Remove the word `Set` from `Set TF = Application.Match("TF", Sheets("Update").Range("1:1"), False)`